# How to delete an attribute when sending a partial object update to Algolia?

Tags: javascript, algolia

I need to use `partialUpdateObject` from the Algolia Javascript SDK to delete an **attribute** from an object that is already in the index.

My scenario is that I have a `description` field on my object that is optional. If the user originally sets a description and then later deletes it, I want to remove the description altogether from the object.

I do not want to overwrite the whole object (without the `description` attribute) because I have some count attributes on the object that I do not want to have to recalculate.

As far as I can tell in the documentation there isn't a way to do it and my workaround is to set the description as an empty string. Is that the recommended approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: you cannot totally remove the attribute from an object with a `partialUpdateObject` operation. As a work-around you can set it to `null`, maybe that's enough for your use-case?

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help! Is there a significant difference between empty string and `null` when it comes to indexing & querying?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to delete the field you can :

- Get your object with the search function
- Store all fields values
- Update (not partial update) your object without passing the field you want to delete